# Broom::tidy function not working for glm2 object?

Tags: r, broom

I'm trying to 'tidy' up a binary regression (so using a log link not a logit link -> so I get RR estimates not OR) using the broom function 'tidy' on a 'glm2' object. However its giving me an error saying

```
> tidy(model, conf.int=TRUE, exponentiate=TRUE)
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
```

Here is a reproducible example of what I mean:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glm2)
library(broom)

data(iris)
glimpse(iris)
table(iris$Species)

##create an outcome

df <-iris %>%
  mutate(outcome = case_when(Petal.Width>2 ~1, 
                             TRUE ~0))

#fit stardard glm 
glm(outcome ~ Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width, data=df, 
    family = binomial(link="log"))
# -> doesnt converge using a log link due to parameter space issues (common in fitting binary regression).
# go to glm2 to fit the model instead, but need starting values for this:
p0 <- sum(as.numeric(df$outcome))/length(as.numeric(df$outcome))
start.val <- c(log(p0),rep(0,2))

model<-glm2(outcome ~ Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width, data=df, 
    family = binomial(link="log"), 
    start = start.val)

##get warnings, but converges
model$converged

##now tidy up and display model
tidy(model, conf.int=TRUE, exponentiate=TRUE)

#error -> wants starting values again? also shows warnings from previous 
# (which are now saying model hasnt converged?)

tidy(model, conf.int=TRUE, exponentiate=TRUE, start=start.val)
# doesnt recognise starting values?
```

Any ideas on how to get `tidy` to work, or do I just do it manually?

Comment: What version of broom are you using? Seems you already filed a issue on the github site: https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/issues/918

Comment: Yes i did log a question there, as when i read through some other issues. I noticed that glm2 doesnt seem to play nicely with broom, so i thought it *might* be an issue. 
Its R v 4.0.2 and  broom version 0.7.0